# Microsoft Project - Tasks do not split if a higher priority task "Leveling Can Split" is set to "No"

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

I have an issue where using "Priority, Standard" levelling that "Leveling Can Split" appears to stop lower priority tasks from splitting. I am trying to ensure that highest priority tasks are completed first and that resources are fully utilised (where possible). I have a mix of tasks which need to be completed in one go while others can be split up to fill in gaps (so that resources are still working on something that is a reasonable priority)

As shown in the screenshot below:

For Jimmy:

- Task 1 is the highest priority and it is prioritised first but has a prerequisite task of 6
- Task 8 is the next highest priority and it is split so that it can be worked on before Task 1 starts, and completed afterwards
- Task 5 is the lowest priority and is scheduled after the balance of task 8

For Dean:

- Task 2 is the highest priority and it is prioritised first but has a
  prerequisite task of 6
- Task 7 is the next highest priority and has
  splitting disabled, therefore the soonest it can be scheduled is
  after Task 2
- Task 4 is the lowest priority and COULD be split to
  start before Task 2 but for some reason it is not. It appears that this occurs whenever a higher priority task has "leveling can split" set to "No" as if the leveling terminates due to this setting.

All tasks at not in-progress and "Split in-progress tasks" is enabled.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Thanks

[image: Example Project]

[image: Leveling settings]

Comment: Hi Dean McClure, welcome. Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Raise the priority of the task you want to accelerate.  That's what it's for.